# Firebase cloud functions node 8 engines fix

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

When I run `firebase serve` there is a warning message: `You're using Node.js v8.12.0 but Google Cloud Functions only supports v6.11.5.` but I already declared `"engines": { "node": "8" },` on my functions/package.json file. And I'm using latest firebase-tools version 5. Any idea how to fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just a warning, and there is no "fix" for it.  It's incorrect, but you can just ignore it.  [File a bug report](http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features) if you feel strongly about it.